# Can I use the RAM/processor of my VPS to run software from my desktop?

Tags: vps

Is it possible to use the powerful RAM/processor of my Virtual Private Server to run a software on my desktop? I tried to run a software directly on the VPS but I think it's missing a good graphics card to work, only the RAM and processing power is good.

Comment: This is called cloud computing.  Sure its possible Amazon has service to do computational calculations,  but the technology isn't there to allow you to run the software on the VPS that is installed on your desktop.

Comment: If you have a fast enough network then you could trying running the programs on the server and using a client (called the X-server) to use a local display.